# Adjektivedeklination without noun

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

> ich würde gerne neue Gartenstühle kaufen. Unsere alten gefallen mir nicht.

In this sentence,  why in the second sentence adjective (alten) ending -en, not -e. There is no noun after adjektive is it because of that? If there was noun there alten should be alte right? Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 1):

It's an ellipsis.

> Unsere alten (Gartenstühle) gefallen mir nicht.

In English, you had to insert *ones*. Such a thing is neither required nor possible in German.

Comment: I think you can omit "ones" in English if using it would create a repetition: "We bought some more garden chairs; I like the new ones but dislike the old." With a capital A "Alten" it would be a substantivised adjective. That doesn't seem to work in this case, but it's certainly possible in other contexts

Comment: In German you can use "solch" for english "one", although it often sounds awkward and artificial: *usere alten solchen gefallen mir nicht*. To paraphrase the slogan of the "Neue Frankfurter Schule": *Die schärfsten Kritiker der Molche waren oftmals eben solche*" (The sharpest critics of the salamanders often were *ones* themselves.)